# Wrong tiles sorting

Tags: unity-game-engine, isometric

I have a problem with Tiles in Unity. When I try to place them I can see this.

[image].

Maybe the sprites are bad but I don`t think so.

I've set individual sorting mode for tiles but it didn't help. Tried to use different sorting orders.

Answer (score 0):

Double-Check Sprite Import Settings: Confirm that the sprite import settings are configured correctly for your isometric tiles. Specifically, check the Pixels Per Unit (PPU) value and the sprite's pivot point. These settings can affect how the tiles are rendered and positioned in the scene.

Verify Shader or Material Settings: If you're using custom shaders or materials for your isometric tiles, ensure that their settings are appropriate for isometric rendering. Pay attention to transparency, blending modes, and any other relevant properties that may impact the visual appearance of the tiles.

Review Tilemap Settings: If you're using Unity's built-in Tilemap system, double-check the settings of your Tilemap component. Ensure that the orientation is set to "Isometric" and that the cell size matches your tile dimensions.